# Custom URL Scheme and http

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Using my iPhone i noticed that when i open a youtube link like http://m.youtube.com/..., this is redirect to the native Youtube app.
I would like to do the same thing but using my custom url scheme, so i would like to have a custom url, if my app is installed in the device this is redirected in it, or if it's not installed, to do something else.
I've tried to register as a custom url scheme the "http://" url scheme, but the is not listening for these urls.

edit-

I've already tried to register my custom url scheme, i want to use an html page, in that page i want to put my custom url scheme, but the problem is that i can't detect, from the web page, if the app is installed in the device

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the **Associated Domains**.

If I understand well your question you need to define your own domain that will be associated to your app. Every time an app will find that specific domain the OS will check if any installed app can handle it.

You need to add the capabilities as specified by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to create your custom URL Schema for that you can open via another app.

Following is the Tutorial where you can create your own URL Schema and use into your app.
[Here is tutorial.](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

You can define custom url schemes that will open your app, but you can't make your app the designated handler for certain domain names so that opening that domain in Safari will launch your app automatically.

And One thing for more detail this solution given into this [question also.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571291/custom-url-scheme-to-native-app-or-website)

Happy coding.

Comment: First link in answer is dead.

Comment: Yup currently that site is down by owner

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your custom URL schemes in Info.plist. With this schema you can launch your app.

Comment: You need to give comment rather then answer.

Comment: @NimitParekh Thanks to let me know. Better provide useful info other then commenting on others answers.